# Getting rid of the default ACF plot title

Tags: r, plot

[image: ACF plot with default title cut off]Im trying to get rid of the default main title (ass2_ts) that you can see on the top . Is there a away to suppress that ?

```
ass2_acf <- acf(ass2_ts,plot = FALSE)
par(oma=c(3,3,0,2))
plot(ass2_acf ,  adj=0.5)

title( "Egg deposition Time Series ACF",line=-1)
```

Many thanks

Comment: add `main=""` inside the `plot` call.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the plot title with the `main` argument:

```
set.seed(2)
d = cumsum(rnorm(50))

acf(d, main="Egg deposition Time Series ACF")
```

[image]

If you want the title inside the plot area, you can get rid of the margin at the top as well. The `mar` graphical parameter contains the margins, in number of lines, on each side of the plot in the order `c(bottom, left, top, right)`. The default is `c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1`. We want to get rid of the top margin in this case. The code below sets the top margin to 0.1 lines and leaves the others unchanged:

```
par(mar=c(5,4,0,2) + 0.1)

acf(d, adj=0.5)
title("Egg deposition Time Series ACF",line=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: The default title disappeared . exactly what i was after . Cheers 
Was it the  + 0.1 that did the trick or the numerical arguments inside the c bracket ?

Comment: `c(5,4,0,1) + 0.1` is the same same as `c(5.1,4.1,0.1,1.1)`, but a bit easier to type. The default margins are `c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1`.

Comment: Run `?par` to see the help for all of the graphical parameters (for base graphics), including `mar`.